# IE7 weird padding issue with custom input submit button

Tags: input, internet-explorer-7, padding

I have custom styled input submit buttons. I have a background image and then I have used padding-left to position the text.

My problem is on IE7 the text is positioned differently even though I have specifically set the padding at 23px.

Please take a look at the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/4zx6p/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mystery was solved when I added text-align:left; you can see the updated fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/4zx6p/12/